# Autorotation Trajectory Datasets?

Tags: helicopter, auto-rotation

I was looking for works/datasets on autorotation trajectories. Now, I have found works like this: [Aponso et al](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/290100128_Automated_autorotation_for_unmanned_rotorcraft_recovery), [Dalamagkidis et al](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/stamp/stamp.jsp?arnumber=5524095), [Abbeel et al](http://heli.stanford.edu./papers/AbbeelCoatesHunterNg_aaoarch_iser2008.pdf)  or [Nonami et al](https://books.google.de/books?hl=de&lr=&id=6H-ANYxUKzwC&oi=fnd&pg=PR1&dq=nonami%20kenzo%20drone%20book%20springer&ots=XAAmj3uszq&sig=f8rI6dAwlLMkG4nS-GpUEANnCLM#v=onepage&q&f=false) (Chapter 6).

However, I have a hard time finding any real flight data of a helicopter during autorotation. Nothing, ranging from full-size helicopters to model helicopters.

I know it's a long shot, but are there any cases where the data would be publicly accessible? Datasets should include (Trajectory, Velocities, Attitude, Main Rotor RPM and if available blade pitch angles)?

I am running out of ideas. If there is no data I am going to get a model helicopter and do it myself :)

Comment: I do not know of any full-size helicopter datasets, but you *might* have some luck using the Px4 Flight Review site: https://logs.px4.io/browse which has publicly available data for drones. Perhaps you find someone who recorded his/her autorotation. Perhaps you can download and filter this data somehow...